# Grabbing HTML from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML files: One acts as a template, supplying the navigation, sidebars, etc., and the other has the main content. I'm trying to figure out how best to insert the content into the template. I need persistent URLs, so my plan was to have the content page essentially replace itself with the template, plugging the text back into the resulting page. I'm really new to front-end programming and I'm suspicious that this may be an anti-pattern, so my first question is about whether I'm barking up the right tree. The problem seems universal, and I'm sure there must be a best practice, though I haven't yet seen it discussed. If this *is* an acceptable way to proceed, then what JavaScript function would allow me to access the HTML of two different pages at the same time?

[EDIT: It's a small page on GitHub]

Comment: If your goal is to use JS as a template engine, don't.

Comment: You would need to do ajax calls to get html from another page but I would say don't do this or depending on browser compatibility you can use the object tag: `<object type="text/html" data="file.html"></object>`

Comment: is your point to have text inserted in places in the template? given that the file will give you the needed text?

Comment: If it resides in the same site structure, you could use `load`.  However, I would advise against it if at all possible.

Comment: This is completely possible, even easy if you use jQuery (if you're new to front-end programming then do yourself a favor and read up on jQuery). This is something that would be best somewhere on the back end, which server side platform are you using? Also is it completely different content every time?

Comment: This is a blog on GitHub, so the simpler, the better. For the time being, I'd rather stick with straight JavaScript, if possible.

Comment: Perhaps XSLT is another approach you could use for your problem. I 'd follow BenM 's advice. Don 't do a template engine with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this. At current implementation HTML is not designed to be template engine. You can use [HTML import](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) but it has not full support in browsers. ([compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports)).

Usually this problem can be solved with:

- **Use frontend framework**. Libraries like angular.js or polymer.js (and [so on](http://todomvc.com/)) usually has support of importing HTML documents in different forms.
- **Build your application HTML**. Task runners like grunt.js usually [has plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-source) that includes HTML.
- Use **server side** technologies to extend your HTML from base layouts

If your application have to be consisted from different HTMLs I recommend you to try [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/). It is polyfill for web components and designed to work in such way by default.

**UPD:**

About edit to your question. It seems like you just need template engine for HTML. You can google for it. I use [nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) - javascript port of python's template engine jinja2. It is lightweight, simple and can be compiled right in browser.

Another way is to use special tools for building static web pages. You have mentioned that your page is blog build from simple HTML pages. Try to use [pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/). It is the static websites (blogs) generator. It is simple and fast. You can build your HTML even on your local machine and just push your HTML pages to github.

Comment: Pls, note that I don't use grunt plugin link to which I have provided by myself but from its description it seems that it does exactly what you need

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "code markup without HTML including." Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @planarian edited UPD to my answer. Pls look, it might be helpful for you